# What is the size and lifetime of a node in a linked-list implementation in C?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

In a linked-list implementation in C (or C++), what is the size of the node and lifetime of pointer variable? For example:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}*ptr=NULL;
```

Now I want to know the size of the node: is it 4 bytes, and if so, how?
Secondly, how long does the pointer live: throughout the execution of the program?
Lastly, is it proper to call `*ptr` an instance variable or data member or an object?

Comment: The size is entirely platform specific to its structure packing.  `sizeof(*ptr)` will eval to the actual size at compile-time if you're really interested (`sizeof(struct node)` works as well). And it lives as long as you let it live. Finally, `next` is a pointer, not an object. You can call it a member variable, and instance variable, an instance member variable, the beat goes on.

Comment: The size of a node as defined in the question would usually be 8 bytes on a 32-bit platform, and either 12 or more usually 16 bytes on a 64-bit platform.  If you found a 16-bit compiler with 16-bit pointers and 16-bit `int` types, then it might be just 4 bytes long, but not otherwise.  There's no guarantee of the sizes I mention; however, most compilers would produce one of the answers I give.

Comment: @rosemary That's a whopper of a question.  I hope you don't fall asleep in reading the answer to match.  Next time, see if you can break your question up into smaller chunks, to get smaller answers.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sizeof is a compile time operation . Node is a structure . So size of node is the summation of all the members size in the structure . 
    So u have an integer and a pointer . Size of node is size of integer + size of pointer . 
  Lifetime : memory is allocated dynamically . Until you call free , node lives . If u perform a delete operation , Good programmer style us used to free the memory allocated for that node .

Comment: While accepted, this is factually wrong. The size of a node is the summation of all the members size __and the necessary padding to maintain memory alignment boundaries__.  A good example of this is that a struct of `integer + pointer` will likely take the same amount of memory as a struct of `char + pointer`.

Comment: And it should be noted that the boundaries are architecture specific and how the compiler aligns to those boundaries can vary by compiler.

Comment: Yes , We need to consider padding also . For example , char and integer are structure members . Size of char is one byte and integer is 4 bytes . But the size of structure will not be 5. It will be more than 5 due to padding .

Comment: Microsoft C compiler aligns on byte boundary.

Comment: @JackCColeman Compilers align to the hardware below.  If the word size is greater than a byte, then greater than a byte is fetched.  Sure, the extra bytes are likely discarded; but a compiler rewrites code for the machine's execution.  It can't set policy for the machine, but it can emulate a different policy at the cost of more clock cycles.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to generally know the size of the node.  However, you can know the size of the node at compile time, for a specific platform and set of libraries.

```
sizeof(struct node)
```

will tell you the size of the node.  Note that it might not be the actual size of all of the members within the node combined.  Occasionally, padding is necessary to have the members within the struct align on memory alignment boundaries necessary for proper operation.

In addition, pointers do not have a specific size.  They are large enough to accommodate the required memory address, but that's the only requirement that they must satisfy.  There are dramatic differences in pointer size between 32-bit and 64-bit environments, and even if not shifting between two supported bit-ness environments on the same hardware, different hardware platforms *may* have different memory requirements to store a pointer value.

Where you get the "4 bytes to store a pointer" is from the popular misconception that all computers that use C are Intel CPUs, in the Pentium family of chips, which can only run 32-bit code.  It was an untrue assumption back then, and it's equally untrue to assume it now.

Even after that is taken into account, arrays of the struct might require between-array-element padding for correct memory alignment.  As a result, even if you know the size of the struct, you cannot assure that an array of `X` elements will fit in a memory area of `X * sizeof(struct node)` bytes.

Use `sizeof(...)` to find the answer you seek, but make sure that pretty much everything you want to take the size of is in the `sizeof(...)` operator.

As far as the life of the pointer, it lives as long as the program is running; however, the value stored in `node->next` might not actually reference a meaningful address.  `node->next` is designed to hold an address, but there are far too many ways to trick `node->next` to point to addresses that do not specify the beginning of a pattern of bits which satisfy the needs of a `struct node`.

This "problem" with the C language was fixed to some degree in subsequent languages meant to "improve" upon C, by making pointer-type operations impossible.  Instead the languages allowed the safe sub-set of pointer operations, which meant that you really didn't have a pointer (so they called it a reference).  Java and C# are two such languages, but there are many that deny the truly dangerous operations on pointers.

It is not proper to call a pointer an instance of a variable, because it really is a variable that holds a memory address.  There is no strict requirement that the memory address it holds contains a bit pattern that will satisfy the "type" of the pointer.  It's just one of those legacy C issues, which C++ preserved in order to be compatible with C.  Also, an instance variable tends to suggest object-oriented terminology, and C cannot (in its default form) provide object-oriented guarantees, so applying object-oriented-programming terminology to C is inappropriate.

Likewise, a struct is not a class, and members of the struct are subject to slightly different rules than members of a class.  The biggest "slightly different" rule is that members of a struct are generally publicly accessible, unless you actually take great care to hide the declaration of the struct from the rest of the program (which will require a lot of C gymnastics to do and make your program still work).

Comment: thnks @edwin for d answer

Comment: @rosemary Glad to help, anytime.

Answer (score 2):

1. The size of node depends on your computer and compiler. Use `sizeof(struct node);` to get it.
    It is not 4 bytes. In a 32-bit environment, it is 8 (4 bytes for `int` and 4 bytes for `struct node *`).
2. The `ptr` lives throughout the execution of program. `ptr` is a global variable.
3. `ptr` is an *instance variable* while `*ptr` means the memory `ptr` points at.